# js как сделать самозагрузку iframe

Tags: javascript

Как сделать чтобы `iframe` при загрузке страницы сам прописывал себе `src`, причем внутри тэга `html`, к примеру `onload="this.src='http://site.ru;'"` перезагружается вечно , нужно без `jquery`

Comment: Не понял проблемы. Чем не подходит написать src как положено, в html? Он динамический? Вам нужно прописывать **айфрейму** src при загрузке самого **айфрейма** или, все же, при загрузке текущей страницы?

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<iframe id="myFrame"></iframe>
<script>
    document.getElementById("myFrame").src = "http://www.cnn.com";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Можно так прописать.
Так же приведи сам код который не работает, с пометкой где и что нужно вставить